# Jekyll: can't sort collection by date

Tags: jekyll

This is making me crazy.

I have this collection `resources`:

```
# _config.yml
collections:
  resources:
    output: true
    permalink: /resources/:name/
```

They all have dates:

```
# /_resources/example.md
---
title: Learn the Web
date: 09-04-2013  
---
```

The pages get generated, and if I try to display it's date, it is displayed correctly, but I also want to sort those by date, and it just doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
{% assign sortedResources = site.resources | sort: 'date' %} <!-- Doesn't work -->
{% for resource in sortedResources %}
  <div>
    {{resource.title}}
    <small>{{resource.date | date: "%d %b %Y"}}</small> <!-- Works -->
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I'm using:

```
▶ ruby --version
ruby 2.1.4p265 (2014-10-27 revision 48166) [x86_64-linux]
▶ jekyll --version
jekyll 2.5.3
```

Thanks

Comment: GOD. This was driving me nuts. I thought I was loosing my mind for a bit there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm currently experiencing the same problem with collections.

While trying to sort on European formatted dates like `dd/mm/yyyy` or `dd-mm-yyyy`, I get a string sort. Even when the `timezone: Europe/Paris` is set in the `_config.yml` file.

The only way to get a collection sorted by date is to use ISO format `yyyy-mm-dd`.

```
# /_resources/example.md
---
title: Learn the Web
date: 2013-04-09  
---
```

And the sort is now working.

**Edit** - This is how jekyll manages 'dates':

```
date: "2015-12-21" # String
date: 2015-12-1    # String D not zero paded
date: 01-12-2015   # String French format
date: 2015-12-01   # Date
date: 2015-12-21 12:21:22  # Time
date: 2015-12-21 12:21:22 +0100 # Time
```

If you don't need Time you can stick to the `date: YYYY-MM-DD` format.
And you have to be consistent across your collection. If you mix String, Date and/or Time Liquid will throw an error like `Liquid error: comparison of Date with Time failed` or `Liquid error: comparison of String with Date failed`

Comment: I have tried this to get my collections sorting and it's not working for me. In fact I can't fathom how it's sorting the collection. Any other ideas what I should check for?

Comment: Have you submitted an issue for this specific problem? I submitted something similar: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/4687

Comment: @LorenRogers, see my answer edit. This is not a bug.

Comment: @DavidJacquel Thanks for the info -- it sounds like this is a documentation issue then. I'll note this is my github issue.

Comment: Note `yyyy-mm-dd` is not a US format. It's ISO and recognized internationally.

Answer (score 10):

If your Collection items have a valid `date` ([ISO 8601 format](https://xkcd.com/1179/)) in the front matter they'll be sorted by date automatically, oldest first.

If you'd like to output more recent items first you can `reverse` the order like so:

```
{% assign sorted = site.resources | reverse %}
{% for item in sorted %}
  <h1>{{ item.name }}</h1>
  <p>{{ item.content }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: For whatever reason, the built-in `sort_by` feature wasn't working for me (for ordinary string/number attributes), so I ended up doing  `{% assign items = site.query_provider | sort: 'order' %}`. Thanks

Comment: were {% assign items = site.query_provider | sort: 'order' %} should be put in?

Answer (score 5):

I got it: the resources where sorted by the date string (eg. `19-06-2015`) which was not correct.

I created my custom filter instead:

```
# _plugins/filters.rb
module Jekyll
  module DateFilter
    require 'date'
    def date_sort(collection)
      collection.sort_by do |el|
        Date.parse(el.data['date'], '%d-%m-%Y')
      end
    end
  end
end
Liquid::Template.register_filter(Jekyll::DateFilter)
```

Used like so:

```
{% assign sortedResources = site.resources | date_sort | reverse %}
{% for resource in sortedResources %}
  <div>{{resource.title}}</div>
{% endfor %}
```